# Get shadows to go behind all elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get dynamic shadows on some divs.  So i am doing the following:

HTML

```
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="div1" class="castsshadow">Div 1</div>
   <div id="div2" class="castsshadow">Div 2</div>
   <div id="div3" class="castsshadow">Div 3</div>
   <div id="div4" class="castsshadow">Div 4</div>
   <div id="div5" class="castsshadow">Div 5</div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

.castsshadow
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #50535C;
    background-color: white;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Javascript/JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).mousemove(function(e){

  $(".castsshadow").each(function(i) {
   var offset = $(this).offset();
   var width = $(this).width();
   var height = $(this).height();
   $(this).html(
    "X Axis : " + e.pageX
    + " Y Axis : " + e.pageY + "<br>"
    + "X Offset : " + offset.left
    + " Y Offset : " + offset.top + "<br>"
    + "Height : " + height
    + " Width : " + width + "<br>"
    + "X Center : " + (offset.left + (width/2))
    + " Y Center : " + (offset.top + (height/2))
   );
   $(this).css({
    boxShadow: -(e.pageX-(offset.left+(width/2)))/10 + "px " + (-(e.pageY-(offset.top+(height/2)))/10) + "px 10px -10px #404040"
   });
  });

 });

});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/feY6C/

The problem I am having, is that the shadows go in front of other div's.  Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: shadows don't have z-index property ;)

Comment: divide your fiddle in to two vertical half parts. when the cursor is on left side.. give `z-index: -1` to left containers and when the cursor is on right side.. give `z-index: -1` to right containers. and also reset the other side containers `z-index` at the same time.

Comment: That's a nice idea, but I am planning for this to remain dynamic for any layouts, ideally, so i don't have that luxury.  I am guessing it's not possible after all :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you'll have to make another div for each one you have now. For example, clone what you currently have and on one of each put shadows, and for the other, put content. You can use JS to make the cloning dynamic. I'll write you a jsfiddle in a bit.

UPDATE

<strike>Here you go, this is what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/feY6C/7/</strike>

Note that I had to disable your JS because it overwrites my child divs (will rewrite it now, but wanted to show you my idea first, I added a fixed shadow `-15px 0`) and that I had to remove the positioning for the parent divs. Each div becomes something like this:

```
<div id="div1" class="castsshadow"><div>Div 1</div></div>
```

And the CSS for them:

```
.castsshadow div {
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
background: white;
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
border-radius: 20px;
margin: -10px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

And here it is with live JS: http://jsfiddle.net/feY6C/31/

The bottom line: I wrapped each div's content inside a child div, made that div absolute with the parent's dimensions and a higher z-index. They are dynamically built, so you never have to worry about them and there are no issues with positioning.

Comment: You're saying do secondary divs behind the first set, and give them a lower z-index?  I hadn't thought of that.  I'd have to consider the issues with positioning.

Comment: Yes, perhaps the top ones should be positioned absolutely over the bottom ones (with the shadow), and having same dimensions. One sec, I'm builing the fiddle.

Comment: You contained the div and pushed inner div forward.  A simple and elegant solution, than you SO MUCH!  It looks kinda cool, don't you think?  I need to add some better maths now.

Comment: Yeah, your idea is very interesting! You can also make use of the double divs to add some nice styling to both of them. I just gave you the raw version. You're welcome! :)

Comment: Yep, it's a very clean solution.  And i often end up using divs contained for cleaner layouts.  So thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to further elaborate my answer; but you can give the div a z-index that is calculated based on the distance from the cursor to the center of the div.

The nearest divs (to the cursor) get lower z-index, the farthest divs get higher z-index.

(Something in the line : distance in pixels / 20 - to give z-index values in a not so high range